# Kubernetes developer setup on linux desktop

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, desktop, docker-ce

I really like the way how kubernetes was [integrated](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#kubernetes) in Docker For Mac. Is there an similar way to setup kubernetes locally on a linux desktop for development/testing purpose? Or is minikube still the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

Minikube is currently your best bet: https://www.docker.com/kubernetes

> We have added Kubernetes support in both **Docker Desktop for Mac and Windows** and in **Docker Enterprise Edition (EE)**.

*Emphasis mine*

Comment: Thanks, i hoped i missed something. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The local-up cluster (`hack/local-up-cluster.sh`) is an option for simple development/testing.

Answer (score 0):

Minikube is local, single-node cluster build with Kubernetes stack.
It works on MacOS, Windows, Linux, and FreeBSD. FreeBSD is not based on
a virtual machine, but it uses native FreeBSD jails for isolation.

As far as I know, there is no alternative solution for easy development of a single-node
Kubernetes cluster with minimal technical knowledge. You only have to download [binary minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases) and start the installation process.

`minikube start`

Finally, when all files are downloaded, installed and configured, Kubernetes configuration file

`$HOME/.kube/config`is also ready for use with kubectl tool.

If you have [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/) downloaded, you are ready to operate on freshly installed 
local  Kubernetes single-node cluster.